# Don't understand sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have set up a Python script that reads an ID from an RFID tag and then checks that tag on a database, and finds the student's name and parent email and sends an email saying that the student arrived (in Greek). But when I run the script I get the following error after scanning a card:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/teliko/1.py", line 28, in <module>
    cursor.execute ('SELECT onoma, email FROM parousiologio WHERE id=?', [id])
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The code itself:

```
import sqlite3
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import string
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader= SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    id= reader.read()

    def email():
       port = 465  # For SSL
       smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
       mail = "deniskeeper@gmail.com"
       message = "Ο μαθητής έφτασε"
       msg = EmailMessage()
       msg.set_content(message)
       msg['Subject'] = f'Ο μαθητής έφτασε.'
       msg['From'] = mail
       msg['To'] = remail

    db = sqlite3.connect('parousies')   
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute ('SELECT onoma, email FROM parousiologio WHERE id=?', [id])
    print (onoma + "" + email)
    email()

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This is running on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Have you tried printing `id` to see if it looks correct?

Comment: Also, `print (onoma + "" + email)` is going to fail, because you do not have a python variable named `onoma`.  You are selecting that column in the SQL query, but Python does not automatically translate that into a local variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon
So I made a script that only reads and prints the ID, and i tried with print(id) and print([id]). The outputs are:

print([id])
[(920125972027, 'Kosmas Raptis                                                           ')]

print(id)
(920125972027, 'Kosmas Raptis                                                           ')

Could the [ and ] be doing this?

Comment: @JohnGordon the `print(onoma + "" + email) ` is not part of the actual code, I just have it for debug purposes, but since it doesn't move on from cursor.execute() I don't know if it works or not. Apparently like you said it won't but still it never runs.

Comment: @KosmasRaptis ***"The outputs are: print([id]) `[(920125972027, 'Kosmas Raptis ')]`"***: `id` is of type `tuple` which is not supported. You have to use: `[id[0]`